# APK crashing when downloading from playstore - debug works fine .The app was developed in reactnative

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

Our app is launched in playstore .But it is crashing .In debug mode it is working fine.We did a process like cd android and then ./gradlew bundleRelease .The .aab is generated successfully .Here are the details of the crash analytics report from google.[crash analytics details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xd1I.png)

Comment: Please Add Details crash analytic report

Comment: I can smell proguard being the culprit here.

Comment: Debug the released app in Android studio (logcat) and share the error here.